# Ngrx - Reducer can't receive action

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm trying to load some cached details when app initializing. I'm using builtin `APP_INITIALIZER` provider of angular.

In this provider I'm running the init method of the `AppService` and loading those cached information, dispatching some actions. 3 of 4 actions are gracefully dispatching but when I try to dispatch order details reducer doesn't get this action and I can't transfer order details to store.

But when I look at redux chrome extension I'm able to see my action that getting dispatch, but if I log incoming actions in reducer I can't see my action.

The weird part it is if I run `loadCachedOrderDetails` method after three seconds later with setTimeOut method, `setCachedOrderDetails` action  dispatched successfully..

What is exactly happening ? How can I dispatch `setCachedOrderDetails` action properly ?

Here is full definition of the provider

```js
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (app: AppService) => () => app.init(),
      deps: [AppService],
      multi: true
    }
```

AppService init method

```js
  init() {
    const request = this.loadCachedRequest();
    if (request) {
      this.loadCurrentLocation(request);
    }
    this.loadCachedBasketItems();
    this.loadCachedOrderDetails();
  }
```

and the method

```js
  loadCachedOrderDetails() {
    const details = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orderDetails'));
    if (details) {
      this.store.dispatch(PanelActions.setCachedOrderDetails({details}));
    }
  }
```

and panel store where I register the reducer

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature(panelFeatureKey, fromPanel.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([PanelEffects]),
  ],
  exports: [
    StoreModule,
    EffectsModule
  ]
})
export class PanelStoreModule {
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in one of the JSON.parse that doesn't throw but ends execution of the task?

Comment: no actually, I also logged details

Comment: That is strange. If you change the order of the dispatches, does anything change?

Comment: nope, still it doesn't dispatch the same action

Comment: But if you wrap it in a setTimeout it works, so it isn't an error of spelling or wrong class. If you put console.log(action) in a reducer, any reducer does it log out the action?

Comment: @DerekKite, well if only I use setTimeOut, without delay it is not available in reducer. (but it seems at redux extension in any case, idk why)

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but try to log out the actions in any reducer, to see if it is there. It may be some error where the reducer doesn't recognize the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `EffectsModule.forFeature` it means this module isn't main one and your app has been initialized already and your module was highly likely lazyloaded or initialized later once app is needed in it.

Therefore you can't rely on any INIT triggers. Because they can emit earlier than your feature has been set and is ready to listen to actions.

but you can simply use constructor of your module to dispatch required actions.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature(panelFeatureKey, fromPanel.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([PanelEffects]),
  ],
  exports: [
    StoreModule,
    EffectsModule,
  ]
})
export class PanelStoreModule {
  constructor(app: AppService) {
    app.init();
  }
}
```

Or simply move the effect and the reducer to the `forRoot` part.

Comment: I wish I have hundres of upvotes to vote this answer, you saved ten hours of debugging. I just created new panel service and move panel related codes there and without any delay it works perfectly fine. because as you mentioned, both effects and store lazy loading and other actions work because they are in root register.